# Software Design in Python and C#

Tags: python, c#, wpf

The scenario I am facing, when simplified, is essentially this:

Let's say that I have a back-end programmer who only knows Python, a front-end/UI programmer who only knows C#, and a client who wants a packaged executable of the program. What tools can be used to implement such an program?

Some more details about the project:

1. The Python developer wants to use libraries like Pandas, Keras, Tensorflow, Scipy, Numpy, etc.
2. The C# developer wants to use Windows Forms or WPF to create the UI.
3. The client will be executing the application on Windows platform. The client will be happy if the packaged application is not huge or slow (pyinstaller sometimes leads to huge executables)

Some things I have considered:

1. IronPython - unfortunately it is too out of date and libraries like Pandas are not supported
2. PythonNet - calls python scripts using interpreter and will not package everything as an executable
3. Communicating data between Python and C# using a local server - this introduces dev time for serialization/deserialization and also decreases robustness.

Comment: All that I can think of is to find a way to functional between the two languages and pass JSON structures

Comment: Buy different programmers instead of software :-(